# How to use multiple instances of Microsoft SQL Server 2016 web edition

Tags: sql-server, multiple-instances, sql-server-2016

I am planning to get SQL Server web edition licence from my server provider

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.130).aspx

SQL web edition has 64 gb ram and 16 core limitation

I will run 3 websites on this server and server has 24 cores and 128 gb ram currently

So it is logical for me if I run 2 instances SQL Server and I can utilize all system resources?

However I have never used two instances of SQL Server before.

So how can I install multiple instances of SQL Server 2016 web edition and use them?

This is my static connection string currently

```
public static string srConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=myDB;uid=sa;pwd=myPW;";
```

Comment: You need to install the second instance with a separate, unique *instance name*  (the first one typically doesn't have an instance name), and then you need to use `localhost\instance` as the "server" name in your connection string - that's about all there is!

Comment: @marc_s thank you for answer. so i have to install another SQL server. this means i guess  no way to install another instance from sql management studio right? and 1 more thing. we only pay one 1 time right? or do we have to pay for each instance?

Comment: Yes, you have to do another full install - cannot just "clone" an instance from SSMS. And please don't ask *me* about Microsoft licensing...... no idea.....

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to go with `Standard` edition. It might be more expensive (about $45K), but you can use all of your 24 cores and 128 gb ram by just one instance.
You do not have to have multi instances, just have everything in different databases. If you are concerned about security, then you can make databases invisible for another user.
In case you want an ability to restart services separately, then it is better to have 2-3 virtual boxes, but in this case you'd have to pay individually for each box.

Comment: 45k is more than 3  years revenue of mine :D ,while web edition costs 25$ monthly. so do you know i can have 2 instance via single web edition license ? currently microsoft forces web developers to use mysql or web edition. no alternative solution is available for indie developers such as standard edition. it is out of question with that astronomical price. if it was like visual studio or windows server price that would be reasonable.

Comment: I do not believe you that MS `forces web developers to use mysql`. Can you give an official link? Web edition works only via `hosting partner`. You must have one, otherwise you go only with regular editions.

Comment: well they definitely force with the price range. only option is web edition and  not every company provide that. can you imagine an indie game developer paying 45k for start up?